# When Running C# script I get an MySQL Error 1292

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have looked around this site and others and have not been able to figure out what I need to fix.  I am getting the error

> "Incorrect date value: '3/24/2018 12:00:00 AM' for column 'start'.

I am using **C#** and **MySql** and i am trying to set a date in the DB named start.  The column is set to Date.

Here is the C# Code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                var postedDate = web.Load(item);
                var dateNodes = postedDate.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/section/section/section/div[2]/p[2]/time");
                var innerPostDates = dateNodes.InnerText;
                DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(innerPostDates);

                DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
                MySqlDateNow = endTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                MySqlEndDate = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                variables.startDate = MySqlEndDate;
                variables.endDate = MySqlDateNow;
```

Then this is the SQL string:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO userproperties_temp(userID,clPostID,start,stop,pageHTML)VALUES('9999','" + variables.postID + "','" + MySqlEndDate + "','" + MySqlEndDate + "','" + item + "')";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to make to string like  MySqlEndDate .Tostring(datetimeformat)

Comment: Stop concatenating text and use parameterized queries, and you won't have these problems.

Comment: As we do not know ether the Declaration of your table nor the culture used inside your database nor in your C# App, we can't help you. Just to mention: The error message and your Format do not match. You used the yyyy-MM-dd format but the MySQL Server converted it to a "MySql default format". Simply Use a Proper parameterized Query and you easly get rid of that!

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce your problem using provided code. Please, create [mcve] to improve your chanses of getting an answer.